# Cognito reset MFA for a user

Tags: amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication

I created a user pool in AWS Cognito with MFA set to **optional**
[image: MFA]

and adaptative authentication as **Optional MFA**.

[image: Adaptative authentication]

The MFA method enabled for users is TOTP, which I enable by calling **SetUserMFAPreference**.

My use case requires that any user that uninstalls their TOTP app or buys a new mobile phone can install it again in their new device by generating a new valid TOTP token.
The only way to generate a new TOTP valid token is by calling **AssociateSoftwareToken**, but it requires an access token that the user does not have as they are not signed in yet.

I tried with **SetUserMFAPreference** setting *enabled=false* but it did not work. Sign in still requires the TOTP challenge.

Is there any way to disable MFA or regenerate a new TOTP token to achieve below behaviour?

Comment: Do you know of any apps that work like this? Do you have an example?

Comment: Open to new approaches as long as the user has a safe mechanism to set up again MFA once they lost their device @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: Understood - does [this](https://medium.com/@akash.verma926/how-to-recover-amazon-cognito-users-who-has-lost-their-totp-devices-8f3472c5c5d5) help at all? If not, please share some code.

Comment: In the end, this function is not allowed in Cognito. So basically, instead of trying to create a new token, we decided to store the existing one and reuse it every time the user wants to reinstall the authenticator app in another device

Comment: Please self answer the question then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a workaround for this problem.

This disable MFA function is not allowed in Cognito. What we did is, instead of trying to create a new token, we decided to store the existing one and reuse it every time the user wants to reinstall the authenticator app in another device.

This way, we do not need to create a new token, just reuse the existing one.